# Reading Multiple .SWF Files in local via JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

i know this subject is so duplicated here or in the net . but! there's no simple method , or i didn't found a SIMPLE METHOD TO READ .SWF FILES IN LOCAL VIA HTML OR JAVASCRIPT ... what i want is something that can reads me : i've some files in directory : 
0001.swf
0002.swf
0003.swf
etc etc 
to 1000.swf ....2000.swf

and i want an index.html , with a button . when i click the button , it loads me the first file in directory which is : 0001.swf , when i click next it loads me : 0002.swf etc etc etc

I found some codes if you want i can post them . but no of them worked .

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a browser app automatically read/modify/delete files from any user's hard drive... That would be a big security issue for the (digital) world.

**possible fix:**
Only option is to run the html page itself from a hard drive folder and put your `.swf` files in same folder location as the `.html` file. When embedding a swf within that html code **use the filename only** (no folder path) in URL. This way you can cycle through multiple SWFs in same hard drive folder.

Comment: i've the code to embed one SWF FILE . my files are all in the same folder as the HTML FILE . but what i want is clicking next to embed the next file name ... HOW TO DO THIS ??? THIS IS MY PROBLEM . I NEED THIS PARTICULAR CODE PLEASE